# Angular HttpClient SerializedName of fields in model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-json

Is there any way to add some attribute/annotation to model class field to mark what is serialized name (question based on `@SerializedName` from `Gson`) of field in json response from server?

E.g. response from server contains fields like `start_date` or `some_date` and I would like to have fields in my model named `startDate` or `acquisitionDate`. In my Spring server fields in response model are annotated with `@SerializedName("start_date")`.

I'm using `Angular 10` and `HttpClient` like this:

```
httpClient.get<MyModel[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/getData')
            .pipe(map(models => models.map(m => Object.assign(new MyModel(), m)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and used library https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer
Also if anyone needs, there similiar libraries https://github.com/weichx/cerialize and https://github.com/kmathy/cerializr